# how to handle the new index after using groupby()?

Tags: python, pandas

My initial Dataframe like this with index 'trade_dt':

```
            stcode  closePrice  
trade_dt                                                        
2011-02-28  601179.SH      8.5600  
2011-02-28  600736.SH    157.9124   
2011-02-28  600243.SH     18.0842   
2011-03-31  002437.SZ     70.8500    
2011-03-31  601988.SH      3.6790
```

and when I using groupby() it generate a new index like this:

```
                       stcode  closePrice
trade_dt   trade_dt                                                        
2011-02-28 2011-02-28  601179.SH      8.5600
           2011-02-28  600736.SH    157.9124    
           2011-02-28  600243.SH     18.0842    
2011-03-31 2011-03-31  002437.SZ     70.8500    
           2011-03-31  601988.SH      3.6790
```

How can I delete the new index in the bottom Dataframe?Thanks!

Comment: My expected output is just like the upper Dtaframe.Please ignore this pointless behavior. I just want to feagure out how to handle the index after using groupby()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `reset_index` with `drop = True`

```
Yourdf=Yourdf.reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```